# Angular, ng-repeat to create multiple sets of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create multiple sets radio input options with ng-repeat, however, it seems that when the elements are being created, they are not given the unique ID I intend ( `"id":"1", "id":"2" or "id":"3"` ) instead they all get named specifically  `'fee[{{ record.id }}]'`, this results in only the  final radio set having a check. What am I missing here?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="fee_control">
  <div ng-repeat="record in fees" >
    {{ record.description }} : 
    <input type="text" value="{{ record.amount }}">
    Active: 
    <input type="radio" name="fee[{{ record.id }}]" value="{{ record.amount }}" checked />
    Inactive: 
    <input type="radio" name="fee[{{ record.id }}]" value="0" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('fee_control', function($scope) {
    $scope.fees = [
                    {"id":"1","amount":"5.00","description":"Approved"},
                    {"id":"2","amount":"2.00","description":"Authorized"},
                    {"id":"3","amount":"2.00","description":"Settled"}
                  ];
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <div ng-repeat="record in fees" >
   {{ record.description }} : 
   <input type="text" value="{{ record.amount }}">
   Active: 
   <input type="radio" name="fee[{{ record.id }}]" value="{{record.amount }}" ng-checked="true" />
   Inactive: 
   <input type="radio" name="fee[{{ record.id }}]" value="0" />
</div>
```

use ng-checked instead of checked :) thanks